# How do I get all parameters and their value in Revit through C#?

Tags: c#, revit-api

```
    public IList<Parameter> GetAllParameters(Reference reference, Document doc, IList<ElementId> elementIds)
    {
        Element element = SelectElement(doc, reference);

        ParameterSet pSet = element.Parameters;

        IList<Parameter> param = new List<Parameter>();

        foreach (Parameter p in pSet)
        {
            if (p.Definition.Name.Equals(element.Name))
            {
                element.GetParameters(element.Name);

                param.Add(p);
            }
        }

        return param;
    }
```

I am supposed to get all parameters from an element in Revit, although, this isn't just working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you already did it. You only need to get the parameter value. Something like this:

```
foreach (Parameter p in element.Parameters)
{
    switch (p.StorageType)
    {
        case RvtDB.StorageType.Double:
            double value = p.AsDouble();
            break;

        // ...

        default:
           string txt = p.AsValueString();
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using RevitLookUp developed by @JeremyTammik, where you can see all the parameters and their values. See: https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup